# Получить код страницы после редиректа методом .click() selenium на ссылку-якорь

Tags: python, парсер, selenium, click

Суть в том, что на неком сайте я прокликиваю, после чего выводится таблица, ее мне нужно сохранить в excel, проблема в том, что я не могу получить html код страницы с таблицей.

P S
driver.page_sourse - не помогает, выводит html исходного url c авторизацией.
и
requests.get(url).text тоже не работает, поскольку страница с таблицей задана ссылкой-якорем, и выводится html код страницы до вывода таблицы

Перерыл весь интернет и не нашел решения, хотя задача достаточно тривиальная.
Надеюсь мне тут помогут :)

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду под  "страница с таблицей задана ссылкой-якорем"? Ссылка с якорем же просто прокручивает страницу до определенного элемента. Это не должно мешать получить код с помощью requests. Насчёт Selenium - что вам мешает авторизоваться? Ззаходите на сайт c помощью Selenium, авторизуетесь, далее переходите на страницу, где ваша таблица и получаете html - driver.page_sourse

Comment: а, да, все верно driver.page_sourse работает, я просто не заметил в выводе сам html таблицы, спасибо, так бы дальше голову ломал.

Answer (score 0):

Пробовали использовать pandas?
import pandas

> > > ds = pandas.read_html(«ссылка»)

Comment: не работает, кидает html страницы до вывода таблицы, спасибо! Предыдущий комментарий заставил перепроверить driver.page_sourse и он работает

Comment: pandas и селениум это даже не близкие вещи